# Take value of variable and run it through array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in the process of building a calculator to determine how long a childs colic is going to last.

I have the calculator working correctly just need it to take the value it gets and run it through the array and match the next closest value to the value shown and then reference it to its associated week.

So for instance if you select week 2 and then week 5 the calculation returns childs colic will end in .5614399999999999 weeks. You would then run the .5614 through the wessel_data array and find that .5614 falls in between week 6 and 7. I would then take the next closest week which is week 7 and show that instead of the .5614. So it should say childs colic will end in .64 weeks. Now that it has found the .64 I want it to output the associated weeks so that it would say childs colic will end in 7 weeks.

This is what I have written to find the next associated value but cant get it to work.

```
function closest (num, wessel_data) {
                var curr = wessel_data[0];
                var diff = Math.abs (num - curr);
                for (var val = 0; val < wessel_data.length; val++) {
                    var newdiff = Math.abs (num - wessel_data[val]);
                    if (newdiff < diff) {
                        diff = newdiff;
                        curr = wessel_data[val + 1];
                    }
                }
           return curr;
     }
```

I also have a fiddle so you can see what I am talking about.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jessemfulton/rguoz7bp/6/)

Comment: If you post code in your question, you should tag what language the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the index of the wessel_data, not the data itself.  That is just for comparing.  So in this function set `curr = val + 1`.  Not `wessel_data[val + 1]`.

You aren't using this function at all in your fiddle so it is hard to tell what exactly you are doing.

My advice is to think of what values you want returned given inputs and work backward from there.

Comment: Ok I added it to the fiddle with an alert. I created another array as a test and call the closest function with the array and the number. I just want to make sure I am doing this right because when I call curr it doesn't show anything. Not sure why.